# Oracle 10gR2 - fix for SSL version following Poodle attack

Tags: oracle, ssl

We use Oracle utl_http to send https requests from within our database (10gR2).
As SSLv3.0 is now considered insecure (POODLE) we need to upgrade to TLS.
How can we ensure TLS usage when sending requests from PL/SQL?
Is a patch to the DB the only solution or is there another way?
Thanks
Terry

Comment: Think you're going to be out of luck on 10.2 - it's too old.

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect you to be able to set the SSL_VERSIONS to 3.1 (TLSv1) and successfully avoid the POODLE vulnerability.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14268/asossl.htm#i1023429